# Sending and receiving text messages (SMS) over iPhone 5 with Bluetooth from Win7

Tags: ios, windows, bluetooth, sms, iphone

I have tried to connect my iPhone via bluetooth to my Windows 7 PC. 
After following some suggestions online, I updated the Broadcomm drivers from here: http://www.broadcom.com/support/bluetooth/update.php

The iPhone now connects, and I was surprised to find an interface for sending messages (MAP MAS-iOS)

[image: Exposed bluetooth services]

As well as the option to connect to the device to send SMS messages:

[image: Available phone operations (iPhone 5S)]

When I pressed Connect I got a functional little interface that shows the battery and reception of my phone:

[image: SMS Editor]

However, when I try to send a text it keeps disconnecting. I can't identify any specific errors.

Has anyone managed to get text messaging via iPhone to work? I couldn't find anything online that shows success (or failure) and I feel like I am very close...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The iPhone doesn't support sending text messages over bluetooth (for security purposes according to apple).

Comment: So why does it publish that interface? For example, it doesn't publish a file sharing interface...

Comment: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3647
Message Access Profile allows devices to exchange messages. It's mostly used for automotive hands-free use.

Comment: I don't think I understand: doesn't that contradict your answer?

Comment: It can read, but not send afaik